# Magento 2 Warning imagecreatefromjpeg error

Tags: php, magento2

I am getting issue regarding Magento 2 Installation and still don't get any solution about it.

I am installing Magento 2 using docker-compose but I keep getting following warning:

```
[Progress: 419 / 833]
Module 'Magento_Theme':

In PatchApplier.php line 167:

Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'imagecreatefromjpeg' not found or invalid function name in /var/www/myshop/vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 72
```

Here is how I added GD support on Dockerfile (FROM php:7.2-fpm):

```
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/ --with-xpm-dir=/usr/include/ --enable-gd-jis-conv
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
```

Here is my current phpinfo() output related gd information:

[image] 
From the snapshot there is no JPEG support listed there.

Here is my OS information:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any help regarding this will be really appreciated since I have been stuck on this for 2 days.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can check from these links : https://www.php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php 
and 
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-or-add-php-gd-support-to-apache/

Comment: I have followed the instruction and use exactly same configuration but the jpeg support is still not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using docker php-fpm, I destroyed the Container, removed all unused and unrelated dependencies from my Dockerfile then rebuild everything then everything seems works now.